# Check TypeScript types in Svelte files from command line

Tags: typescript, svelte

I run `tsc --noemit` to ensure the are no type errors in the codebase. Unfortunately, it does not seem to check .svelte files.

Is there a way to make it work? I can see the type errors in .svelte files open in VS Code, so I think it has to be possible somehow with existing tooling.

Also I'm using the official @rollup/plugin-typescript I'm aware there is also rollup-plugin-typescript2 which checks types on build and may be an alternative solution, but I prefer to not enforce types on build and check types separately as I currently do.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Tools_and_testing/Client-side_JavaScript_frameworks/Svelte_TypeScript

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `svelte-check` for this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/svelte-check

`tsc --noemit` only knows about TypeScript files, not Svelte files. `svelte-check` fills that gap and is able to check both TS and Svelte files.

When using it with TypeScript the recommended way to run it is: `svelte-check --tsconfig ./path/to/your/tsconfig.json` . Assuming your `tsconfig.json` is in your project root and you run that from the root, do `svelte-check --tsconfig ./tsconfig.json` . It's advised to install `svelte-check` locally, so you can add a `script` to your `package.json` with the mentioned command.

Comment: Also you may want to add `--threshold=error` or `--threshold=warning` to ignore linting-level hints  and only get the type errors.

Comment: @dummdidumm, `svelte-check --tsconfig ./tsconfig.json` doesn't respect tsconfig.json excludes array.